# How to add extra variables to TSLM model

Tags: forecast, fable

I'm trying to add some extra variables in my model like below:
No problem adding new values to my numeric variables, but when I try to add more variables I got an issue

```
library(fpp3)

google_2015 <- gafa_stock %>% 
filter(Symbol == "GOOG", year(Date) == 2015) %>% 
mutate(trading_day = row_number()) %>% 
update_tsibble(index = trading_day, regular = TRUE) %>% 
mutate(qt = quarter(Date)) %>% 
mutate(dow = as.factor(weekdays(Date)))

google_2015_stretch <- google_2015 %>% 
stretch_tsibble(.init = 3, .step = 1) %>% 
filter(.id != max(.id))

fit_cv <- google_2015_stretch %>% 
model(tslm = TSLM(Close ~ Volume + Low + qt + dow))



f <- new_data(google_2015_stretch, 1) %>% 
mutate(Volume = 1447601, 
       Low = 700, 
       qt = quarter(Date),
       dow =  as.factor(weekdays(Date)))

fc <- forecast(fit_cv, new_data = f) 

fc %>% accuracy(
google_2015, 
list(rmse = RMSE, mae = MAE, mape = MAPE, mase = MASE, crps = CRPS, winkler = winkler_score)
) %>% 
arrange(rmse)
```

Please, if someone could help me, will be appreciated

Comment: *"...I got an issue"* Which exactly?

Comment: Actually I got two: 

    f <- new_data(google_2015_stretch, 1) %>% 
    mutate(Volume = 1447601, 
           Low = 700, 
           qt = quarter(Date),
           dow =  as.factor(weekdays(Date)))

Error:  Problem with `mutate()` input `qt`.
x do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
ℹ Input `qt` is `quarter(Date)`.

   fc <- forecast(fit_cv, new_data = f) 

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `tslm`.
x contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
  Unable to compute required variables from provided `new_data`.